# Facebook link sharer preview image is not showing full preview on some phone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

My site contain all the meta tags required to share on facebook. image, url, site_name, app_id, title , description etc. all the necessary things.

But when somebody share the page, it doesnot show full preview of the image on some phone. On web and some other phone its working fine.

I tried everything. I read full documentation of facebook about web sharing. I tried recommended size of 1200x630 pixel, also the minimum size of 600x315 pixel. Issue is still there. Setting og:image:width and height manually don't really make any change also.

````
  ```  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<<PAGE ID>>" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<<Site Name>>" />
    <meta property="og:url"           content="<<URL>>" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title"          content="Some title" />
    <meta property="og:description"          content="Play now" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="<<image url>>" />
    ```
````

Comment: Show us a screenshot of what's happening. Facebook does crop images on mobile in different ways than they crop on desktop; I suspect it's simply that. We tend to keep the important part of the share image (words, focus of the image) in the center so if the sides get lopped off it's still fine.

Comment: https://ibb.co/DGcxccr

https://ibb.co/GHpnfv7

Checkout these two photos. Both are same in resolution but

 rendering full or half preview in different phones.  I want these photo to be rendered fully on all phone.

Comment: As I suspected, it's just Facebook cropping things differently in different scenarios. There's nothing you can do to prevent this, to my knowledge. As I said, our solution has been to put the important bits of the image in the center (and avoid text on the left/right hand sides), so if it gets cropped the image still looks OK.